# i got message 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, ide

I'm trying to get selenium to work with goorm, but it doesn't work.
I am using goorm IDE which is a cloud service.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:Users/chromedriver.exe")
```

When run,  I get this message:
'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedri

Comment: Are you sure that your path is correct?

Comment: Put it in C:\Windows

Comment: @jykim can you please let us know that did it solve your problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/chromedriver.exe")
```

Add the path of chromedriver.exe in `Path` which is in `Environmental Variable`

If you are using `Windows`

1. Right click on `My Computer` and go to `Properties`
2. Select `Advanced system settings`
3. Go to Tab `Advanced`
4. Click on `Environment Variables`
5. In `System Variables` Section Search for `Path` Variable
6. Double click on it and add the path of `chromedriver.exe` in the list of its `value`

Comment: In windows `/` slashes are not used for paths, instead, you should use double `\\` slashes.

Comment: Try adding the path of ```chromedriver.exe``` in ```Environmental Variable```

Comment: @Marcos we can use ```/``` in windows as well for Path

Comment: Try adding the path of chromedriver.exe in ```Path``` which is in ```Environmental Variable```

Comment: Right click on My Computer and go to Properties >> Select Advanced system settings >> Go to Tab Advanced >> Click on Environment Variables >> In System Variables Section Search for Path Variable >> Double click on it and add the path of chromesriver.exe in the list of its value